# SFTP InboundChannelAdapter poller issue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

My SFTP Poller config and @InboundChannelAdapter config follows

I have ThreadPoolTaskExecutor configured with a queue capacity as 5
SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource is configured with setMaxFetchSize(5)
the polling interval is configured as every 20 seconds.
Please refer to the bean config

```
    @Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory,
        CustomSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter customSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter) {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpInboundDirectory);
    CompositeFileListFilter<LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpInboundFileFilterPattern));
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(customSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter);
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
    return fileSynchronizer;
}


@Bean
public CustomSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter customSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore) {
    return new CustomSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, StringUtils.EMPTY, sftpFileWatchInterval);
}

@Bean("taskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(5);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("sftp-th-exec");
    // Incase of 'Q' is full, we have to delegate the task to the caller thread to run the task.
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
    return executor;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "inboundFileChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "0/20 * * * * *", 
            taskExecutor = "taskExecutor"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer) {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
            sftpInboundFileSynchronizer);
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(sftpLocalDownloadedDirectory));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setUseWatchService(true);
    source.setMaxFetchSize(5);
    
    source.setLocalFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpInboundFileFilterPattern));
    
    return source;
}


// SFTP File Audit
@Bean("inboundFileChannel")
public MessageChannel inboundFileChannel() {
    DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
    channel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            String fileName = String.valueOf(message.getHeaders().get("file_name"));
            log.info("[SFTP]-Received file[{}] from remote SFTP [{}] to local directory [{}]", 
                    fileName, sftpConfig.getSftpInboundDirectory(), sftpConfig.getSftpLocalDownloadedDirectory());
            
            log.info("[SFTP]-Meta data store (received-on) updated for file [{}]", fileName);
            return message;
        }
    });
    return channel;
}

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundFileChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
public Message<File> extractZip(Message<File> message, @Header("file_name") String pgpInvoiceZipFileName, 
        @Header("file_originalFile") String localFilePath) {

                 return message;
    }
```

I have 10 files stored in the Remote SFTP folder.

When I run the application, I can see 5 files are moved to the local folder and start processing it. Since I have 5 concurrent threads and each thread takes 30 seconds to complete, so the 5 files are taking (5*30 seconds = 150 seconds) 2:30 Minutes to complete.

But my poller is configured with 20 seconds but the next set of 5 files is fetched only after the completion of 5 files (after 2:30 minutes)

Ideally, it supposes to fetch files from the remote every 20 seconds but it is not working that way (after the completion of 5 files - after 2:30 minutes only it is picking the next set of files)

But when I reduce the poller interval to 5 or 10 seconds, it fetches files every 5 or 10 seconds.
Could you help me what could be the issue?

### Log for your reference

**2023-05-06 18:12:32.287** DEBUG 14284 --- [  sftp-th-exec1] o.s.i.s.i.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer    : TraceId[] - 5 files transferred from '/tungsten/invoice/uk/ingress/test/inbound/'

2023-05-06 18:23:20.005 DEBUG 14657 --- [  sftp-th-exec2] sageSource$LocalFileReadingMessageSource : TraceId[] - Added to queue: [/Users/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/10.txt, /Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/4.txt, /Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/3.txt, /Users/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/2.txt, /Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/1.txt]

**2023-05-06 18:14:08.524** DEBUG 14284 --- [  sftp-th-exec2] o.s.i.s.i.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer    : TraceId[] - 5 files transferred from '/tungsten/invoice/uk/ingress/test/inbound/'

2023-05-06 18:25:08.214 DEBUG 14657 --- [  sftp-th-exec1] sageSource$LocalFileReadingMessageSource : TraceId[] - Added to queue: [/Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/5.txt,/Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/9.txt, /Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/8.txt, /Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/6.txt, /Users/selvanta/Applications/javaworkspace/sftp-test/./files/local/7.txt]

Comment: Not clear how that supposed to work if all your threads are busy with current set of files. What is the point to fetch more if we cannot handle them yet. You statement about `5 or 10` does not make sense for the same reason: if all the thread in the pool are busy, the next task will be performed only when we got a free thread.